# Multiple menus in Gantry

Tags: joomla-3.x, menu, gantry

What I'm trying to do is create 2 separate menu systems for a website.   1 menu would drive the Product Information & sales portion of the website.   The second menu would drive the online play portion of the website.   I've created a top menu that can interact to change between the sides of the side.   My problem is that I want the site to select the appropriate menu when you click on the link in the top menu.

You can view the test site at [www.p3proswing.com/site3](http://www.p3proswing.com/site3).   When you click on P3ProSwing it would go to the current menu.   When you click on P3 Live, I want the secondary menu that appears to be in the same style as the original menu but replace the original menu.

I'm using Gantry 4.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue.    I needed to duplicate the gantry template.  On the second template, I simply chose the P3 Live Menu under Menu.  Then under Assignments (in the template), I chose the applicable template for each page.

This resolved the menu structure and also the issue for having specific menus only for the appropriate pages.

Answer (score 1):

Create 2 menus and 2 menu modules, 1 for your play side and 1 for your sales side. In the module options just assign specific menu items where each one should show up.

Menu > Manage > Add New Menu -> name if sales
Menu > Manage > Add New Menu -> name if play

Add menu items to each of those menus you want your users to see

Extensions > Modules > New Module > Menu

Assign the menu module to the correct menu you created and assign specific menu items to it and voila done.

Comment: I've done that.   The P3 Live Menu is only assigned to the P3 Live Home page (which has the articles on it).   You see this menu when you click the P3 Live option.   I've currently assigned it to a different location just so it would display.   Note that it is not formatted like the P3ProSwing is either.  Even though all settings are the same.

Comment: I've also got Main Menu (which is the P3ProSwing site).  That is assigned to all pages except the P3 Live Home Page.  But it still appears when clicking the P3 Live link.  But you'll note the P3 Live menu does go away when clicking back on the P3ProSwing top link.  It's like Gantry has fixed the Main Menu on every page somewhere.

Comment: I figured out how to make the P3 Live menu to look the same by adding the gf-menu class to the Menu Class Suffix of the P3 Live Menu module.  So the only issue left is making the Main Menu disappear when on the P3 Live section of the site.

Comment: On your P3Live menu, where you added gf-menu as the menu class you need to add a space in front of that class declaration.

Joomla is weird when it adds a class to an item like that, it directly appends the class name without the appropriate space between classes. Right now if you inspect your menu you will see that the CSS class is called 'menugf-menu'. Adding the space in the backend will make that 'menu gf-menu'.